# Retrieve the reaction time in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I wrote the following script to measure the respondent's reaction time for each question. My question is how can I retrieve the reaction time?

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function(){

 var starttime = new Date().getTime();

 var that = this;

 this.hideNextButton();

 this.questionclick = function(event,element){

  if (element.type == 'radio') {
   var endtime = new Date().getTime();
   var reactiontime = endtime - starttime;
   document.getElementById("QR~"+this.questionID).value = document.getElementById("QR~"+this.questionID).value + "X" + reactiontime + ",";
  }
 that.clickNextButton();
 }

});
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Retrieve it from where?  ("QR~"+this.questionID) is wrong.  It should be ("QR~"+that.questionId). Also, your question types are mismatched: element.type == 'radio' assumes a single answer multiple choice, but then you try to update the text value.

Comment: @T.Gibbons thanks to your reply. I want to retrieve from the JS code, i.e. reactiontime = endtime - starttime; I don't know if it is possible to include a column in the data spreadsheet for the data of reaction time. Instead of update the text value, how can I update the multiple choice value? Please advise. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save reaction time to an embedded data variable.  Define reactiontime as an embedded data variable in the survey flow prior to the question block. Then:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function(){
    var starttime = new Date().getTime();
    $('NextButton').hide();

    this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        if (element.type == 'radio') {
            var endtime = new Date().getTime();
            var reactiontime = endtime - starttime;
            Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('reactiontime', reactiontime);
            $('NextButton').click();           
        }
    }

});
```